# Verify $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {7 \sin x}{\sqrt{5x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Verify $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {7 \sin x}{\sqrt{5x}}$$

I want to say that the answer is D.N.E. because of sin.

If anyone can tell me if I am right and help explain why it would be D.N.E. I would be grateful.

Comment: I don't think it is DNE because it oscilates but each oscilation is smaller than the previous one. I would say the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: 
$$ -\frac {7}{\sqrt{5x}}\le \frac {7\sin{x}}{\sqrt{5x}} \le  \frac {7}{\sqrt{5x}} $$ 
If you do not know the squeeze theorem, 
 
 Note that the LHS and RHS tend to $0$ as $x\to \infty$, squeeze theorem tells us the middle must also tend to $0$, as $x\to \infty$

Comment: ...and sandwich theorem for completion.

Comment: @Rustyn-Yazdanpour ok so the LHS is $-\infty$ and the RHS is $\infty$ so I have to find the middle hence my answer will be 0

Comment: Both side tends to zero, because x is in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is clearly $0$. Your numerator oscillates perpetually between $\pm 7$, while your denominator diverges to $+\infty$. While squeeze theorem is instructive, demonstrative, and du rigeur, you might want to ponder the reason I used the word "clearly" in evaluating a limit. Your considering the possibility of D.N.E. is my only concern here.